# How do I specify multiple header rows when using SQL to query an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to query an Excel spreadsheet using SQL. The problem I'm facing is that one of the sheets I would like to query has 2 header rows. This is a sheet from a report I receive weekly from an external source and have an archive going back 3 years, so simply removing the extra row isn't an option.

Is there any way to tell Excel(/SQL) to treat both rows as headers (or to ignore the first row altogether - the important header information is in the second row)?

here is my connection string if it makes any difference:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0"";"
```

Thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query a range of cells starting from row 2:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:S100]
```

The troublesome part is finding what the end of the range should be.  You could put in a ridiculously large number, but then you'd have to add special handling for the rows of NULL at the end.